# shibsp::ConfigurationException, why the service provider isn't logging any additianal information?

Tags: shibboleth, shibboleth-sp

I'm setting up, on a test environment with CentOS 7, SSO with Shibboleth SP and Shibboleth IDP.
After all configurations, if I try to access a protected source on the server got only an error page:

shibsp::ConfigurationException at (http://server_ip/secure/index.html)

None of the configured SessionInitiators handled the request.

I can find the same message on apache logs (/var/log/httpd/error_log) but in shib_d logs (shibd_warm.log, shibd_d.log) there is nothing about that error.
Is there some permissions that need to be set? Or this is the correct behavior?

I think that the error is on metadata files, but the missing logs things is driving me crazy....

PS: if I try to override the login visiting manually the page "http://server_ip/Shibboleth.sso/Login?entityID=my_idp_entity_id" I can reach the login page and the logs files are correctly updated.

UPDATE:

I've configured the Shibboleth embedded Discovery Service (for now with only one IDP) and I have succesfully reached the iIDP login page after requesting the protected resource, and also the logs where correctly updated.
This is the configuration I will use and deploy, but why with only one IDP I cannot login?
Here are the different SSO tag in shibboleth2.xml
One IDP:

```xml
<SSO entityId="my_idp_entity_id">
  SAML2 SAML1
</SSO>
```

Discovery service:

```xml
<SSO discoveryProtocol="SAMLDS" discoveryURL="http://ip_address/shibboleth-ds/index.html">
  SAML2 SAML2
</SSO>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get log file, the problem was the permissions of "shibd.log".
Even if was created by the shibd service, the owner of this file war root, and only a part of log was reported.

Resolved by changing the user/group owner of the file

```
chown shibd /var/log/shibboleth/shibd.log
chgrp shibd /var/log/shibboleth/shibd.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Configures SSO for a default IdP. To properly allow for >1 IdP, remove entityID property and adjust discoveryURL to point to discovery service. You can also override entityID on /Login query string, or in RequestMap/htaccess.

To idp:

```
        <SSO entityID="https://idp-test.website.org">
          SAML2
        </SSO>
```

To WAYF:

```
        <SSO Location="/Login" 
            discoveryProtocol="SAMLDS" discoveryURL="https://discovery.site.org/test">
            SAML2
        </SSO>
```